# Objects shown at wrong place in render but not in viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I've been setting up the scene as I usually do, placing all objects in their respective places. When I go to render the scene, I notice the body is not showing up and then look in the distance to see it hasn't even moved in the scene. Has anyone encountered this before?

[image: the body is selected - zoomed in]

[image: full screen of Blender]

[image: full screen of Blender Render]

And yes, I've tried to place Origin at Geometry, apparently even in the viewport, the body is there in the middle but it's invisible even though it's in the place??

I'm a beginner at this so I will try my best to understand your answers, thank you! If needed, I can also provide the .blend file so just ask.